# Does the majority A-grade browsers cache content over https to disk?

Tags: caching, ssl, https

I have read somewhere that javascript and css files that only get cached in memory sooner or later get pushed out by other content. Is this true? Are there any other issues regarding cashing SSL-objects?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firefox only caches HTTPS content to disk if the Cache-Control: Public response header is set.

There's more information about this and other HTTPS tuning tips in the following blog post:

http://blog.httpwatch.com/2009/01/15/https-performance-tuning/

Comment: And IE caches on disk even if the Chache-Control: Public is not set?

Comment: Yes, so long as caching hasn't been prevented (e.g. Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache)

Answer (score 0):

If i am not wrong JS and CSS files get copied to the temp directory. With this it really helps for the browser to speed up the download process.

I am not sure regarding in memory object as its in memory i think as soon as the session is over its done.